# Why does MySQL equal sign matches wrong entries?

Tags: mysql, sql, equals, sql-like

I'm running a select query on two tables and searching the matching entries with an equal sign. In my understanding, MySQL should only return entries exactly matching the WHERE condition, however it's returns entries like when I use the LIKE statement:

[image]

Any explanations why would the first row be returned as a result of the query?

EDIT:

Here's the query:

```
SELECT `ts`.`ticker_symbol`, `sm`.`id` AS `matchescount`, `sm`.`ticker_symbol_ids`
FROM `mk_ticker_symbols` `ts`, `mk_submissions` `sm`
WHERE `sm`.`ticker_symbol_ids` = `ts`.`id` AND `ts`.`id` = "1506"
```

EDIT 2:
Here's the SQL Fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5550b/1/0

EDIT 3:
Here's the SQL Fiddle with JOINs:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5550b/2/0

Comment: I can't read that query, could you put the text in your question.

Comment: You should look into upgrading to ANSI-92 joins.  http://my.vertica.com/docs/6.0.x/HTML/index.htm#15163.htm

Comment: I'm not using `JOIN`s alltogether in this query, I need exact match and high performance as well as to keep the query simple. `JOIN`s would work right, no doubt, but it's not clear why this query doesn't work right.

Comment: I see two tables in your `FROM` clause and an equality between those two tables in your `WHERE` clause.  How is that not a `JOIN`?

Comment: you are doing an implicit inner join with your comma: `From x, y`.  Can you please create a sql fiddle (sqlfiddle.com) and post the markup here?  Include your table schemas and some sample data

Comment: I get that now, but still, the JOIN is without percentage signs, which means the match should still be exact.

Comment: Adding sarcasm to your question is not likely to bring more upvotes or get the previous downvotes reversed.

Comment: I don't mind downwotes but would appreciate the reason of them so I can improve my future questions. Noone likes being punished without even knowing what for.

Comment: The old syntax, with just listing the tables, and using the `WHERE` clause to specify the join criteria, is being deprecated in most modern databases.

Comment: I'm puzzled by the rollback

Comment: Since TICKERs are no longer than 5 characters, don't bother normalizing to an 4-byte id.  Instead use `ticker VARCHAR(5) CHARACTER SET ascii`.  This will eliminate some joins, speed up queries, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Piero,
The one with JOINs can be corrected. `CAST()` within `JOIN` will fix the issue.

```
INNER JOIN `mk_submissions` `sm`
    ON `sm`.`ticker_symbol_ids` = CAST(`ts`.`id`  AS CHAR(10))
```

I know you are not looking for solution, but I still post it.

The problem is VERY interesting.
I searched online, and did some trial-error on my DB. I have no explanations....
I tried to put `1506,` in the second, or third place in comma separated list - the query works fine.
So, I have a feeling, that in case of `JOIN` with comma-separated list, comma gets treated as wildcard 'end of string'...

If you ever find an explanation, please post it here.

Comment: Thank you very much for looking into the roots of the issue before posting a feedback. It indeed looks like comma is like a wildcard, not only with explicit JOINs but with implicit ones too, like SELECT -- FROM table1, table2. This might be a bug in MySQL. Maybe I should report it. I will definitely post back if I find an explanation.

Answer (score 2):

When [evaluating expressions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/type-conversion.html), MySQL converts both arguments (in this case) to floating point numbers to compare them. This is because one is a string, and one is an integer, which results in the final condition in the link above being applied.

> In all other cases, the arguments are compared as floating-point
>   (real) numbers.

So what is the floating point equivalent of the string "1506,..."?

Running the following on my test server:

```
SELECT "1506,3101,26673,26745,2277,1216,26847,26865,20711,1468,26947,233,20539,26985"+0.0
```

Results in:

```
1506
```

Which of course equals the floating point version of the integer 1506.

So, everything is behaving as expected. At least, assuming you expect this floating point comparison to be happening.

Answer (score 0):

I can't give a full explanation for the problem, but I have a solution.

`ts.id` is likely and INTEGER so your where clause should be

```
`ts`.`id` = 1506
```

(remove quotes from the number).

Also you should use a join instead of a where clause to match the tables:

```
FROM `mk_ticker_symbols` `ts`
JOIN `mk_submissions` `sm` on sm.ticker_symbol_ids = ts.id
```

Comment: Same result is returned with integers without the quotes. Why should I use JOINs? This query should work as expected, or why if not?

Comment: JOINs are faster and better. Run an EXPLAIN on both queries.

Comment: I'm really not looking for other solutions but want to know why this one fails.

Comment: Added fiddle with JOINs, no difference.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this issue. I was comparing string to integer here:

> `sm`.`ticker_symbol_ids` = `ts`.`id` AND `ts`.`id` = "1506"

The problem is that, this is converted to integer internally for comparison:
 `1506,3101,26673,26745,2277,1216,26847,26865,20711,1468,26947,233,20539,26985`

Because of the comma, MySQL thinks it's a decimal or float with the floating point, and everything after the comma is omitted for comparison. So it becomes `1506` instead of  `1506,3101,26673,26745,2277,1216,26847,26865,20711,1468,26947,233,20539,26985`, and that matches the `WHERE` condition.

@cyadvert and @Willem_Renzema were absolutely correct.

To resolve the issue
I only needed to:

> CAST(`ts`.`id`  AS CHAR)